# How to select strings in a nested list from a list of indexes

Tags: r

I have a list (within a dataframe) of strings. I also have a list (the same size as the list in the dataframe) with numbers corresponding to indices.
I would like to extract those elements in the first list that correspond to the integers in the second list.

Here is my synthetically generated data

```
columnSentence<-list(c(",", ",Biopsies taken from top of stricture-metal marking clips in situ.", 
",Diaphragmatic pinch:40cm .,She has a small hiatus hernia .", 
"Dr. Martin, Marche Date of procedure: 2009-11-11 Endoscopist:", 
"Dr. Sullivan, Shelby Second endoscopist: Dr. al-Basha, Mahfoodha Medications:", 
"Extent of Exam: GOJ Indications: Follow-up ULCER HEALING Procedure Performed: Gastroscopy (OGD) Findings:", 
"Fentanyl 12.5mcg Midazolam 6mg Instrument: FG5", "HALO 90 done with good effect Endoscopic Diagnosis:", 
"He is on Barrett's Screeling List in October 2017 at St Thomas'.", 
"Hospital: Random NHS Foundation Trust Hospital Number: J6044658", 
"No evidence of Barrett's oesophagus, short 2 cn hiatus hernia.", 
",Oesophageal biopsies taken from three levels as requested.", 
",OGD today to assess for ulceration/ongoing bleeding.", "Patient Name: Jargon, Victoria General Practitioner:", 
"Post chemo-radiotherapy stricture", ",The varices flattened well with air insufflation.", 
"Tiny erosions at the antrum.", "We will re-book for 2 weeks, rebanding."
), c("Date of procedure: 2008-06-15 Endoscopist:", "Dr. al-Safi, Lutfiyya", 
"Dr. Kekich, Annabelle Second endoscopist: Dr. Needham, April Medications:", 
"Duodenitis with a small erosion .", "Endoscopic Diagnosis:", 
"Esophageal candidiasis", "Extent of Exam: Pylorus Indications: Weight Loss Procedure Performed: Gastroscopy (OGD) Findings: Duodenum:", 
"Fentanyl 125mcg Midazolam 7mg Instrument: FG6", "Hospital: Random NHS Foundation Trust Hospital Number: Y6417773 Patient Name: Powell, Destiny General Practitioner:", 
",STOMACH: diffuse gastritis with angiodysplasia and punctate bleeding site on greater curve mid body - no obvious ulcer- antrum scar ?,No immediate complications.", 
",Z-line at: 38cm - Bravo placed at 32cm- good positionat check endoscopy."
), c("Body Polyp- Pedunculated .,Several erosions/small ulcers in inflammed antrum.", 
"Date of procedure: 2007-10-27 Endoscopist:", "Dr. Rogers, Monica", 
"Dr. Sullivan, Shelby Second endoscopist: Dr. al-Basha, Mahfoodha Medications:", 
",DUODENUM: Normal to D3.", "Endoscopic Diagnosis:", "Extent of Exam: GOJ Indications: Follow-up ULCER HEALING Procedure Performed: Gastroscopy (OGD) Findings:", 
"Fentanyl 125mcg Midazolam 6mg Instrument: FG2", "Hospital: Random NHS Foundation Trust Hospital Number: B6072011", 
",Lax cardia with small hiatus hernia but no erosive oesophagitis.", 
"Patient Name: Martinez-Santos, Ana General Practitioner:", "Post chemo-radiotherapy stricture ,Extensive neoplastic looking esophageal lesion Esophageal candidiasis", 
"Stomach-"))
```

The index list:

```
myIndexes<-list(c(2L, 4L), 1L, 2L)
```

How can I extract the sentences corresponding to the `myIndexes` list?

Comment: @user63230 why? It is fake data. Synthetically generated. But im flattered that you thought it was real :)

Comment: nice fake data!

Comment: @user63230 .....Seeing as you are interested...https://github.com/sebastiz/FakeEndoReports

Comment: thats a great initiative

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `Map` to extract (`[`) the sentences of the `list` ('columnSentence') based on the corresponding `list` indexes in 'myIndexes'

```
Map(`[`, columnSentence, myIndexes)
```

---

Or use `map2` from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
map2(columnSentence, myIndexes, `[`)
```